# Build Html in the view based on values of two columns

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

The data in the table looks like :

```
   Label  Rowid ColumnId SetID   labelValue 
    Address   1     1       0       abc 
    City      1     1       0       efg
    State     1     1       0       ca
    Zip       1     1       0       90031   
    Dir       1     2       0       EN
    plat      1     2       0       00
    Sqft      1     2       0       123
    Prop      1     3       0       akl
    Status    1     3       0       act
    LP        1     3       0       183
    SP        1     3       0       194


I need the HTML like  this  :



<ul>
    <li> Address : abc  </li>
    <li> City : efg </li>
    <li> state : ca </li>
    <li> zip : 90031    </li>   
    </ul>
    <ul>
    <li> Dir : EN   </li>
    <li> plat : 00  </li>
    <li> Sqft : 123 </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
    <li> Prop : akl </li>
    <li> Status : act   </li>
    <li> LP : 183   </li>
    <li> SP : 194   </li>   
    </ul>
```

Model :

```
namespace MR.Models
{
    public class FDVM
    {
        public FDVM()
        {
            DSet = new List<FDSet>();
        }
    ........
        public List<FDSet> DSet { get; set; }
    }

    public class FDSet
    {
        public FDSet(){    }    
        public string rowId { get; set; }
        public string columnId { get; set; }
        public string setId { get; set; }
        public string label { get; set; }
        public string labelValue { get; set; }             
    }
}
```

View :

```
@if(Model != null)
{

    <div class="row contentHeaderInfo">



         @foreach (var rowList in Model.DSet.Where(a => Convert.ToInt64(a.setId) == 0).ToList())
         {
             @foreach (var colList in rowList.Where(a => Convert.ToInt64(a.rowId) == rowList.rowId).ToList())
            {
                <ul>
                    @foreach (var item in colList.DSet.Where(a => Convert.ToInt64(a.columnId) == colList.columnId))
                    {
                        <li>
                            @item.Label  @item.labelValue 
                        </li>

                    }
                </ul>
            }

         }

    </div>
}
```

I need some help in the for loop.

Comment: What's wrong with the for-loop? Is it not producing what you want?

Comment: it is not producing the output as I wanted

Comment: What's producing? Can you post that? It will make it easier to find what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="row contentHeaderInfo">
     @foreach (var groupedItems in Model.DSet.GroupBy(a => new {a.rowId, a.columnId}))
     {             
        <ul>
            @foreach (var item in groupedItems)
            {
                <li>@item.Label  @item.labelValue</li>
            }
        </ul>            
     }
</div>
```

Comment: thank u.  If I would like to add a condition in the first foreach say setId = 0 ?

Comment: `Model.DSet.Where(a => a.setId == 0).GroupBy(a => new {a.rowId, a.columnId})`

Comment: Jookyn inside the second foreach I want to put the data inside an achor tag for certain properties. For example : if the label is Zip then  <li> item.Label  <a href ="abc"> item.labelValue </a> </li>.